# Convert a webpage to an image (thumbnail)

Tags: php, ajax, image, web, gd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to export the whole page or html content with Highcharts not just the chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328457/how-to-export-the-whole-page-or-html-content-with-highcharts-not-just-the-chart)

I'd like to be able to generate a thumbnail from a given web-address on the fly (and store it for future use). This needs to be done on the server (linux) without using too many resources.

Alternatively, is there a way to do this "invisibly" on a client and then upload the screenshot tot he server via an AJAX cal or something?

Thanks.

Comment: Could be helpful http://www.websitethumbnail.de/